# How can I fix Flask bootstrap javascript vulnerabilties?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, flask

I am using Flask with boostrap version Flask-Bootstrap==3.3.7.1 for my webapp.

Lighthouse is telling me these are vulnerable:

```
Bootstrap@3.3.7 
jQuery@1.12.4
```

My code that is related to these is very minimal and looks like this:

index.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}
...
```

base.html

```
{% block head %}
{{ super() }}
{% endblock %}
...
{% block scripts %}
{{ super() }}
{% endblock %}
```

When I inspect the html code I see that these are being including with the super():

```
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

How can I fix this? My flask-boostrap is already at the most recent version.

Comment: the version you would want as a replacement is 3.4.1

Comment: Why are you using such an old library? Bootstrap 3 has been [unsupported for more than 3 years](https://github.com/twbs/release). [Flask supports Bootstrap 5](https://bootstrap-flask.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Comment: @isherwood I suppose it's because a well-known Flask tutorial suggests to use Flask-Bootstrap rather than Bootstrap-Flask or manual integration.